# Pentaho (spoon): generate primary key for many rows in SQL

Tags: sql, primary-key, pentaho, kettle, spoon

I have a case: to transfer data from access database to SQL. I have faced with a problem how to create a lot of new primary keys in SQL.

When I had been transfering previos tables, I used Generator Random Values to generate Random String. The new key I cut to 5 figures.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTgDU.jpg)

But now I have a lot of row 900 000 and about 200 new keys are consisted.

I could not use Add sequence because primary key has a length of 5 figures (char(5)).

I think I can use java to create a key and find this script, but I do not understant how made work it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dowFV.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrhC8.jpg)

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomString {
    public String nextString() {
        for (int idx = 0; idx < buf.length; ++idx)
            buf[idx] = symbols[random.nextInt(symbols.length)];
        return new String(buf);
    }
    public static final String upper = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static final String lower = upper.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    public static final String digits = "0123456789";
    public static final String alphanum = upper + lower + digits;
    private final Random random;
    private final char[] symbols;
    private final char[] buf;
    public RandomString(int length, Random random, String symbols) {
        if (length < 1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (symbols.length() < 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(random);
        this.symbols = symbols.toCharArray();
        this.buf = new char[length];
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZF88.jpg)

My database does not have any sequence to use Add sequence and Use DB to get sequence, but has a function to generate keys. How can I use this function? Or not?

This is a statistic of lose data. May I create a cycle to re-generate key in such situation?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQXSk.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of create random keys, use a sequence the convert the sequence in number with a high radix (for example with the javascript `id_as_char = id_as_int.toString(36)`).

Of course, you have other ways !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help. I added else one line to add "0" before string.

```
id = id.toString(36)
while (id.length < (5 || 2)) {id = "0" + id;}
```

*00zzm
00zzn
00zzo
00zzp
00zzq
00zzr
00zzs
00zzt
00zzu
00zzv
00zzw
00zzx
00zzy
00zzz
01000
01001
01002
01003
01004
01005
01006
01007
01008
01009
0100a
0100b*

It is like this https://gist.github.com/endel/321925f6cafa25bbfbde

```
Number.prototype.pad = function(size) {
  var s = String(this);
  while (s.length < (size || 2)) {s = "0" + s;}
  return s;
}

(1).pad(3) // => "001"
(10).pad(3) // => "010"
(100).pad(3) // => "100"
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you left the sequence handling to the sql server? which database are you using?
if you use mysql or postgres you can create a new column with serial type, and the creation of this serial unique consecutive number will be handled much better at db level.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: I use MS SQL and cannot create a new columns, because I have a concrete database. I do not create the database, I try to fill in it.

Comment: i that case a recommend to create uuids as primary keys, reducing options to found colissions between unique keys. Use the "Generate random value" step, and choose UUID4